# CONVERT decimal DAYS to TIME format

Tags: sql, oracle, time, format, hour

Hello iam a newbie in sql and i need your help.

I have the following table:

```
    start_date      |     end_date          
02.08.2012 09:27:19 |  06.08.2012 07:53:00  
06.08.2012 06:58:58 |  06.08.2012 13:42:33
05.06.2012 14:35:58 |  05.06.2012 14:42:31
```

I need to display the duration between start_date and end_date.

I did it like this: **end_date - start_date = duration**
but it displays a decimal value (see below table - field duration).

**I need field duration to display like this: HH:MM:SS**  -  not decimal.

```
    start_date      |     end_date         |         duration        | I need it like this
02.08.2012 09:27:19 |  06.08.2012 07:53:00 | --> 3.93450231481481    |    94:25:41
06.08.2012 06:58:58 |  06.08.2012 13:42:33 | --> 0.280266203703704   |    06:43:35
05.06.2012 14:35:58 |  05.06.2012 14:42:31 | --> 0.0045486111111...  |    00:06:33
```

If something is uncertain i will try to explain.
I hope you can help me. Have a nice day.

Comment: Have a look: http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_get_the_time_difference_between_two_date_columns

Answer (score 3):

The subtraction of the dates gives you the number of days. You can turn them into an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` value using the [`NumToDSInterval`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm) function.

With start date `02.08.2012 09:27:19` and end date `06.08.2012 07:53:00`, the result is close but not quite what you want (and notice the float-type rounding thing where 41 seconds becomes 40.9999999...):

```
SQL> SELECT NumToDSInterval(
  2    TO_DATE('06.08.2012 07:53:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') -
  3    TO_DATE('02.08.2012 09:27:19', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DAY') AS Elapsed
  4  FROM DUAL;

ELAPSED
-----------------------------
+000000003 22:25:40.999999999
```

But it's a good starting point because once the elapsed time is in an `INTERVAL` type you can [`EXTRACT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm) days, hours, minutes and seconds. I'd do it something like this:

```
WITH spans AS (
  SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(end_date - start_date, 'DAY') AS Elapsed
  FROM myTable
)
SELECT
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM Elapsed) * 24 + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM Elapsed) || ':' ||
  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM Elapsed) || ':' ||
  ROUND(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM Elapsed), 0) AS duration
FROM spans
```

I tried this with your first set of dates and it worked just fine; the `ROUND` made the seconds come out correctly as 41.

---

**Addendum** OP needs to use this logic in a view, and I'm pretty sure a CTE (Common Table Expression, otherwise know as "WITH foo AS (query)") won't fly for a view.

To use this in a view, move the CTE to a subquery instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myView AS
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM Elapsed) * 24 + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM Elapsed) || ':' ||
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM Elapsed) || ':' ||
    ROUND(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM Elapsed), 0) AS duration
  FROM (
    SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(end_date - start_date, 'DAY') AS Elapsed
    FROM myTable
  )
```

Comment: I implemented your code like this but it says ORA-00936: missing expression.  Select WITH spans AS (
  SELECT end_date - start_date AS Elapsed
  FROM my_date_table
)
SELECT
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM Elapsed) * 24 + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM Elapsed) || ':' ||
  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM Elapsed) || ':' ||
  ROUND(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM Elapsed), 0) AS duration
FROM spans  from my_table;

Comment: @user2588995 - Ed posted the entire query; you don't need the `select ... from my_table` that you've wrapped around it. The `WITH` clause selects the difference from your table; the `SELECT` then uses that to format the results, effectively. You can think of the `WITH` as a temporary view.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I need to put it in a view. How do i do this? It says missing esxpression. I read that i cant put with clause in a view ? My view: create or replace view order as select customer_id,name,start_date,end_date from cust_order

Comment: I think you're right that the `WITH` doesn't work with views. You can get the same result by moving the `WITH` piece into a subquery. I used `WITH` purely by reflex; the subquery will work just as well. Please see the addendum to my answer above, which uses a subquery.

Comment: Thank you for reply Ed Gibbs. If i start the new code it says: ORA-30076 invalid extract field for extract source.  I guess the query :select end_date-open_date as Elapsed  displays a decimal value so it cant extract hour, minute and second? I hope you can help me. Have a nice day

Comment: Sorry about that! I left out the `NumToDSInterval` function around the end and start dates - that's what turns the decimal value into an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` value so you can `EXTRACT` the various time components. Please see the last query in my updated answer; that should be a lot closer to what you need. Note that the `NumToDSInterval` function takes two arguments: the first is your date math (`end - start`) and the second is the constant `'DAY'`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint concerning NumToDSInterval. In my case the elapsed time is always positive, so I reformatted the output with a regex to look a little nicer like so: Regexp_Replace(NumToDSInterval(a.end - a.start, 'DAY'), '\+0*|\..*', '')

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you want hours exceeding one day.  The following gives you days, hours, minutes, seconds, and works up to 31 days.  The idea is to convert this to a date and then use `to_char()` for the conversion:

```
select to_char(cast('01-Jan-2000' as date) + duration,
               'dd hh:mi:ss')
```

Not ideal, but quick.

Comment: I am using Oracle 12c and had to change 'dd hh:mm:ss' to 'dd hh:mi:ss' to return minutes and not month.

Comment: @jamesduca . . . That was a typo in the original answer.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a built in oracle function.  Try the Date SUB as seen here 
[Oracle Docs / MySQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html)

This will allow you to set the precision on the time that is returned.

Comment: I think you probably meant [timediff](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff), but these are still MySQL functions and don't work with Oracle RDBMS.